# Server upgrade configuration - raid vs. multiple drives vs. combo raid / backup

Tags: centos, raid, redhat, hard-drive, hardware

We're upgrading our Linux box, and moving from CentOS (quad core AMD, 8GB RAM, SATA drive) to RedHat OS (dual quad core Xeon, 8GB RAM, SAS drives) and was wondering... what will provide the best possible outcome in terms of hard drive configuration:

1. OS on 146GB SAS, Data (including backup) on separate 146GB SAS
2. OS, data, and backup on dual 450GB SAS in RAID configuration
3. OS, data on dual 146GB SAS in RAID configuration, with backup on third drive

Looking to maximize performance (PHP applications primarily), speed of backup processes, which run once per day, stability, and security. Thoughts? Comments?

Comment: 4. RAID 10 with 3 drives. If it works because of grub and Raid10.

Comment: I will consider this as a future upgrade. Is this something that's difficult to do once everything has been setup, or is this something that needs to be done with the initial configuration?

Comment: You have to do it in the initial setup. But it depends on your raid controller. Some raid controllers allow you to have raid 10 with 3 drives, linux mdraid also allows this. It will be faster than using raid 5 or raid 1, but if you are using linux mdraid you need grub2 to be able to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading that correctly, you have 2 or 3 drives... If you have 2 drives, use RAID-1 for sure. If you have 3, use RAID-5. Having 2 drives mirrored and a 3rd by itself just for local daily backups is fine too, if you can stand to be without daily backups for a few days when that drive fails.